# Use multiple cooldowns discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to use multiple cooldowns (for invalid commands and command cooldowns), but I get `Redefinition of usage` for both of the `on_command_error` events.

This is what I have currently:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        myEmbed1000 = discord.Embed(description=f":x: {random.choice(silly_e)} {ctx.author.name}, that is not a vaild command!", color=0xDD2E44)

        await ctx.reply(embed=myEmbed1000)

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        cooldownem = discord.Embed(description=f"{random.choice(silly_e)} **{ctx.author.name}**, please wait after {round(error.retry_after)} second(s)!", color=0xfae93a)

        await ctx.reply(embed=cooldownem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use two `on_command_error` events. If you want to catch multiple errors (cooldown, invalid command, etc.). You should only use one event and create multiple `if/elif` statements:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        myEmbed1000 = discord.Embed(description=f":x: {random.choice(silly_e)} {ctx.author.name}, that is not a vaild command!", color=0xDD2E44)
        await ctx.reply(embed=myEmbed1000)

    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        cooldownem = discord.Embed(description=f"{random.choice(silly_e)} **{ctx.author.name}**, please wait after {round(error.retry_after)} second(s)!", color=0xfae93a)
        await ctx.reply(embed=cooldownem)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works